# Certain Text if condition is not met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this working formula that is used for tracking the oldest open ticket for my Ticket tracker sheet -

```
=MIN(IF(('2022'!F:F="Open")+('2022'!F:F="Awaiting")+('2022'!F:F="Hold"),'2022'!G:G))
```

but would like to modify it so instead of showing 1/0/1900 when no condition is met(aka there's no open tickets) would like it to show the words " no Open tickets" not sure how to use the conditions to accomplish this.. any help would be appericated

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? Using entire column references within an array formula like that is not at all a good idea.

Comment: I get what your saying but I am dealing with sheets with less than 100 lines

Comment: You didn't say what version of Excel you have? Also, just one version of your formula has to process more than 4 million cells, even if in reality only several hundred contain data. I can help you with a far more efficient construction if you confirm your Excel version.

Comment: Using office 2016

Comment: Thanks. You say that you want it to return "No Open Tickets" if there are no entries of "Open" in column F? But what if there are some entries of "Awaiting" or "Hold"?

Comment: Want to get the oldest(Min ticket) if the status is either open, awaiting or on hold. but if none apply then no open tickets

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement in first instance (that way a 0 will be a true '0' corresponding to the min when criteria are met) - screenshot refers:

```
=IF(SUM((D5:D10="Open")+(E5:E10="Awaiting")+(F5:F10="Hold"))=0,"no condition",MIN(IF((D5:D10="Open")+(E5:E10="Awaiting")+(F5:F10="Hold"),G5:G10)))
```

[image: no condition met]

...this comapares to the following, i.e. when condition(s) are met

[image]

*(same formula as above)*